# Trying to install pyramid-arima in a Jupyter Notebook and getting some errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, arima, pyramid-arima

I'm trying to run this.

```
pip install pyramid-arima
```

Then, call the library like this.

```
import pyramid
from pyramid.arima import auto_arima
```

The whole stack trace is pretty huge. I don't know if it makes sense to copy/paste everything here, but it seems like these are the errors.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pyramid-arima
  Building wheel for pyramid-arima (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-220wpwid/pyramid-arima_40cd20c892a148f5bdcfdb35358beede/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-220wpwid/pyramid-arima_40cd20c892a148f5bdcfdb35358beede/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-iic20x9e
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-220wpwid/pyramid-arima_40cd20c892a148f5bdcfdb35358beede/
  Complete output (263 lines):
  Partial import of pyramid during the build process.
  Requirements: ['Cython>=0.23', 'numpy>=1.10', 'scipy>=0.9', 'scikit-learn>=0.17', 'pandas>=0.19', 'statsmodels>=0.9.0']
  Adding extra setuptools args
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  blis_info:
    libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  openblas_info:
  C compiler: gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC
  
  creating /tmp/tmpqqj97lwv/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpqqj97lwv/tmp/tmpqqj97lwv
  compile options: '-c'
  gcc: /tmp/tmpqqj97lwv/source.c
  gcc -pthread /tmp/tmpqqj97lwv/tmp/tmpqqj97lwv/source.o -L/usr/lib64 -lopenblas -o /tmp/tmpqqj97lwv/a.out
    FOUND:
      libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
      library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
      language = c
      define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
  
    FOUND:
      libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
      library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
      language = c
      define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
  
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building extension "pyramid.__check_build._check_build" sources
  building extension "pyramid.arima._arima" sources
  build_src: building npy-pkg config files
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid
  copying pyramid/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid
  copying pyramid/_config.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid
  copying pyramid/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/__check_build
  copying pyramid/__check_build/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/__check_build
  copying pyramid/__check_build/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/__check_build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/__check_build/tests
  copying pyramid/__check_build/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/__check_build/tests
  copying pyramid/__check_build/tests/test_check_build.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/__check_build/tests
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/_build_utils
  copying pyramid/_build_utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/_build_utils
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/_build_utils/tests
  copying pyramid/_build_utils/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/_build_utils/tests
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/compat
  copying pyramid/compat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/compat
  copying pyramid/compat/python.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/compat
  copying pyramid/compat/pandas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/compat
  copying pyramid/compat/numpy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/compat
  copying pyramid/compat/matplotlib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/compat
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/compat/tests
  copying pyramid/compat/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/compat/tests
  copying pyramid/compat/tests/test_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/compat/tests
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/datasets
  copying pyramid/datasets/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/datasets
  copying pyramid/datasets/woolyrnq.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/datasets
  copying pyramid/datasets/wineind.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/datasets
  copying pyramid/datasets/lynx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/datasets
  copying pyramid/datasets/heartrate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/datasets
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/utils
  copying pyramid/utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/utils
  copying pyramid/utils/wrapped.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/utils
  copying pyramid/utils/visualization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/utils
  copying pyramid/utils/testing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/utils
  copying pyramid/utils/metaestimators.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/utils
  copying pyramid/utils/array.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/utils
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/utils/tests
  copying pyramid/utils/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/utils/tests
  copying pyramid/utils/tests/test_wrapped.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/utils/tests
  copying pyramid/utils/tests/test_vis.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/utils/tests
  copying pyramid/utils/tests/test_testing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/utils/tests
  copying pyramid/utils/tests/test_meta.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/utils/tests
  copying pyramid/utils/tests/test_array.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/utils/tests
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima
  copying pyramid/arima/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima
  copying pyramid/arima/warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima
  copying pyramid/arima/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima
  copying pyramid/arima/stationarity.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima
  copying pyramid/arima/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima
  copying pyramid/arima/seasonality.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima
  copying pyramid/arima/auto.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima
  copying pyramid/arima/arima.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima
  copying pyramid/arima/approx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima/tests
  copying pyramid/arima/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima/tests
  copying pyramid/arima/tests/test_stationarity.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima/tests
  copying pyramid/arima/tests/test_c_arima.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima/tests
  copying pyramid/arima/tests/test_arima.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima/tests
  copying pyramid/arima/tests/test_approx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima/tests
  running build_ext
  customize UnixCCompiler
  customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
  building 'pyramid.__check_build._check_build' extension
  compiling C sources
  C compiler: gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC
  
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/__check_build
  compile options: '-I/home/ibv_pmo_rstudio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/ibv_pmo_rstudio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c'
  gcc: pyramid/__check_build/_check_build.c
  gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -g -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -g build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/__check_build/_check_build.o -L/usr/lib64 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/__check_build/_check_build.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  building 'pyramid.arima._arima' extension
  compiling C sources
  C compiler: gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC
  
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima
  compile options: '-DHAVE_CBLAS -I/home/ibv_pmo_rstudio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Ipyramid/arima/_arima_fast_helpers.h -I/home/ibv_pmo_rstudio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c'
  gcc: pyramid/arima/_arima.c
  cc1: warning: pyramid/arima/_arima_fast_helpers.h: not a directory
  In file included from /home/ibv_pmo_rstudio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822,
                   from /home/ibv_pmo_rstudio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                   from /home/ibv_pmo_rstudio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                   from pyramid/arima/_arima.c:308:
  /home/ibv_pmo_rstudio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
   #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
    ^~~~~~~
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c: In function ‘PyInit__arima’:
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:25487:3: warning: ‘tp_print’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     __pyx_type___pyx_array.tp_print = 0;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.8/object.h:746,
                   from /usr/include/python3.8/pytime.h:6,
                   from /usr/include/python3.8/Python.h:85,
                   from pyramid/arima/_arima.c:38:
  /usr/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:30: note: declared here
       Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
                                ^~~~~~~~
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:25491:3: warning: ‘tp_print’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     __pyx_type___pyx_MemviewEnum.tp_print = 0;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.8/object.h:746,
                   from /usr/include/python3.8/pytime.h:6,
                   from /usr/include/python3.8/Python.h:85,
                   from pyramid/arima/_arima.c:38:
  /usr/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:30: note: declared here
       Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
                                ^~~~~~~~
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:25502:3: warning: ‘tp_print’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     __pyx_type___pyx_memoryview.tp_print = 0;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.8/object.h:746,
                   from /usr/include/python3.8/pytime.h:6,
                   from /usr/include/python3.8/Python.h:85,
                   from pyramid/arima/_arima.c:38:
  /usr/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:30: note: declared here
       Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
                                ^~~~~~~~
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:25511:3: warning: ‘tp_print’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     __pyx_type___pyx_memoryviewslice.tp_print = 0;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python3.8/object.h:746,
                   from /usr/include/python3.8/pytime.h:6,
                   from /usr/include/python3.8/Python.h:85,
                   from pyramid/arima/_arima.c:38:
  /usr/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:30: note: declared here
       Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
                                ^~~~~~~~
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionSave’:
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26129:21: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       *type = tstate->exc_type;
                       ^~~~~~~~
                       curexc_type
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26130:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       *value = tstate->exc_value;
                        ^~~~~~~~~
                        curexc_value
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26131:19: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     curexc_traceback
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionReset’:
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26138:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                          ^~~~~~~~
                          curexc_type
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26139:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                           ^~~~~~~~~
                           curexc_value
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26140:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        curexc_traceback
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26141:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       tstate->exc_type = type;
               ^~~~~~~~
               curexc_type
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26142:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       tstate->exc_value = value;
               ^~~~~~~~~
               curexc_value
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26143:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
               curexc_traceback
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c: In function ‘__Pyx__GetException’:
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26198:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                          ^~~~~~~~
                          curexc_type
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26199:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                           ^~~~~~~~~
                           curexc_value
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26200:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        curexc_traceback
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26201:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       tstate->exc_type = local_type;
               ^~~~~~~~
               curexc_type
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26202:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       tstate->exc_value = local_value;
               ^~~~~~~~~
               curexc_value
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:26203:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
               curexc_traceback
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionSwap’:
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:27811:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                          ^~~~~~~~
                          curexc_type
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:27812:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                           ^~~~~~~~~
                           curexc_value
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:27813:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        curexc_traceback
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:27814:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
       tstate->exc_type = *type;
               ^~~~~~~~
               curexc_type
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:27815:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
       tstate->exc_value = *value;
               ^~~~~~~~~
               curexc_value
  pyramid/arima/_arima.c:27816:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
       tstate->exc_traceback = *tb;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
               curexc_traceback
  error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_CBLAS -I/home/ibv_pmo_rstudio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Ipyramid/arima/_arima_fast_helpers.h -I/home/ibv_pmo_rstudio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c pyramid/arima/_arima.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima/_arima.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/pyramid/arima/_arima.o.d" failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyramid-arima
  Running setup.py clean for pyramid-arima
```

I have two questions.

1. Is there some way to do a pip install  and require Python/Jupyter to automatically install all required dependencies?.
2. Is there an easier way to run an ARIMA model over a data set that consists mainly of locations and profits over time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have compiled dependencies of arima. You probably want to use something like [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) and enable [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/) to install that using conda. Note that this is now named [pmdarima](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pmdarima) on conda.

This will directly install pre-compiled packages instead of compiled them locally.

With conda, you can also create and environment file, and tell conda to install [everything in this file](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) which is easy when you want to share it. I guess that respond to 1. With pip you can do similar things but with [`pip install -r requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files)

Jupyter will not in itself install packages when you start a notebook for security reasons.

For 2) you likely want to ask this separately as people will get stuck on the installation part and not read till the end.

Comment: These naming conventions seem to change way to frequently. Your recommendation appears to be working! Thanks!

Comment: Great to  hear. Yeah, the naming conventions can be hard. Sometime it's for good technical reasons, sometime for legal ones.